# Calculate original volatile content of a degassed mineral

Tags: geochemistry, planetary-science, moon, isotopic

A lunar apatite sample has a relatively low OH content of 5 ppm, but a an elevated D of 11,000‰ (vs. SMOW). Assuming that water had an original figure of around -100‰ or so, how do I estimate the amount of water present before degassing?

Comment: It would be easier with the oxygen-18 signature

Comment: What's the prior work you have put into this? We're not here to solve your homework problems.